# Is it necessary to set field as volatile

Tags: java, multithreading

Is it necessary to set `balance` volatile, if we use method `deposit` in multithreads? for example:

```
new Thread(()->{
  for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
     account1.deposit(1);
  }
}, "t1").start();

new Thread(()->{
  for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
     account1.deposit(1);
  }
}, "t2").start();
```

It is said that the locks such as `synchronized, Lock` can guarantee that the current thread has to access latest value not the cached value.

```
class BankAccountSynchronized {
    private long balance;

    public BankAccountSynchronized(long balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public synchronized void deposit(long amount) {
        balance += amount;
    }
    
    public long getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }
}
```

Comment: `volatile` isn't necessary, but `getBalance` then needs to be synchronized as well.

Comment: because you change the balance in deposit method and deposit method is synchronized , it isn't necessary to use volatile for balance.

Comment: @MustafaÇil It is necessary (absent a `synchronized` on `getBalance()`) if other threads want to be guaranteed to be able to see the updated value using `getBalance()`. So either the fields must be `volatile`, or `getBalance()` must be `synchronized` as well for correct behaviour (for usages of the `BankAccountSynchronized` class not shown here).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel yes right. I said same. Because the deposit method is synchronized it is not necessary to use volatile for balance. But if  deposit method was not synchronized, volatile should have been used for balance.

Comment: @MustafaÇil No, that is not how it works. If `deposit` is not `synchronized`, you might get missed updates because `+=` is not atomic (e.g. thread1 reads current value, thread2 reads current value, thread2 adds and updates, thread1 adds and updates, then the deposit of thread2 is missing). I'm talking about other threads obtaining the current balance. For that to be guaranteed to work correctly, `balance` must be `volatile` or `getBalance()` must be `synchronized`, otherwise threads might not see an up-to-date value due to the specification of the Java Memory Model.

Comment: Yes, you either would need to make `getBalance()` synchronized, or make the field volatile.  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.3.

Comment: @VGR It's not sufficient to make it volatile if you're incrementing it unsynchronized.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel you are right. I commented this way because I didn't see the getBalance method being called.

Comment: @shmosel But the incrementing **is** currently synchronized.

Answer (score 2):

To summarize the Comments on the Question…

Your current code is not thread-safe. To make it so, you must do any of three things:

- Make `getBalance` method `synchronized`.
- Mark `balance` member field as `volatile`.
- Replace `long balance` member field with [`AtomicLong`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html).

Both accessors are `synchronized`:

```java
class BankAccountSynchronized {
    private long balance;

    public BankAccountSynchronized(long balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public synchronized void deposit(long amount) {
        balance += amount;
    }
    
    public synchronized long getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }
}
```

Primitive member field as `volatile`:

```java
class BankAccountSynchronized {
    volatile private long balance;

    public BankAccountSynchronized(long balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public synchronized  void deposit(long amount) {
        balance += amount;
    }
    
    public long getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }
}
```

Third option is to replace `long` primitive with `AtomicLong` object. No need for `synchronized` at all, not in this particular example scenario. So rename class. And no need for `volatile`.

```java
class BankAccountThreadSafe {
    private AtomicLong balance = new AtomicLong( 0L ) ;  // Initialize in declaration to ensure instance exists before any accessors execute. 

    public BankAccountThreadSafe(long balance) {
        this.balance.set( balance );  // Atomic operation. 
    }


    public void deposit(long amount) {
        this.balance.addAndGet( amount ) ;  // Atomic operation. 
    }
    
    public long getBalance() {
        return this.balance.get() ;  // Atomic operation. 
    }
}
```

Personally, I prefer the third option using `AtomicLong`.

- Using the `Atomic…` types screams out to the reader that we are protecting a resource being accessed across threads. Keeping the programmer one step away from the desired payload means the `Atomic…` types are a constant reminder to think about thread-safety.
- To my mind, using `AtomicLong` avoids the confusing subtleties of the other solutions.